# Android: can't display a toast

Tags: android, toast

I have a problem to display a toast instead of another toast if already been viewed. I have  two activity, in the first Activity toast  is displayed and i have this code:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.q_050);
 String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("sent");
// at this line--> if(str.equals("activity_two")){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 else{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.checkpoint), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

in the second activity  in the back button I included this:

```
  Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
                b3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
                       public void onClick(View v){

                           Intent myIntentActivity1 = new Intent(Q_051.this,Q_050.class);
                           myIntentActivity1.putExtra("sent", "activity_two");
                           startActivity(myIntentActivity1);
```

and the problem in logcat is this :

```
 11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.quizcelebrita/org.quizcelebrita.Q_050}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at org.quizcelebrita.Q_050.onCreate(Q_050.java:32)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-09 16:29:51.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1510):     ... 11 more
```

the line where the problem is detected is this:

```
   if(str.equals("activity_two")){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 Bundle value = getIntent().getExtras();
 String str= value.getString("sent").toString();
```

in

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("sent");
```

also, String comparison in Java should be performed through the equals method

```
if(str.equals("activity_two"))
```

Comment: have you changed the if condition as I ve mentioned?

Comment: this last line gives me problem in the log

Comment: what line, what problem and what log

Comment: it might also happen that the string is null, yo know

Comment: 1) read the documentation in order to understand the basis of android. 2) check always for null values, the last codition could be `if (str != null && str.equals("activity_two")) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null pointer exception on the if condition you mentioned
Try debugging your application and put a breakpoint on this line :-

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("sent");
```

Check if str is getting any value or not. My guess that it is not receiving any string so that's why it is showing null pointer exception